# SwiftUI read Data of Entity with already selected UUID

Tags: core-data, swiftui, entity, uuid

after researching und trying out 2 days I haven't found any solution. I hope you can give me a Tip. Im still Beginner level.

Goal:
After choosing a bean (Picker with selection works fine) I would like to store the elected bean.roastStyle to CurrentBeanStyle (that I initialized with "dark").
In other words I got the UUID (chooseBeanID) of the entity and want to read out the rest of the attributes of the entity to store the to Current...

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Dial_In: View {
  
   @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
   @FetchRequest(entity: Bean.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var beans: FetchedResults<Bean>
    
   @State var chooseBeanID: UUID? = nil
   @State var CurrentBeanStyle = "dark"
   
   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Form {
                    Section {                  
                        Picker("Bean", selection: $chooseBeanID) {
                            ForEach(beans, id: \.id) { bean in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(bean.roaster ?? "unknown")
                                    Text(bean.name ?? "unknown")
                                    Text(bean.roastStyle ?? "unknown")
                                 }.tag(bean.id)
                             }
                         }
                           .onReceive([self.chooseBeanID].publisher.first()) { (value) in
                                if self.chooseBeanID == nil {
                                }
                                else {
                                    self.SaveCurrentBeanData()
                                }
                           }
                     } 
                } 
           }      
       }.navigationBarTitle("Dial in", displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
        func SaveCurrentBeanData() {

        // Code Hier ............

        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it way easier by not storing the UUID in the State, rather store the selected `Bean` object in the State.

```
@State var chooseBeanID: Bean?
```

Then for the `Picker` with Proxy Binding

```
Picker("Bean", selection: Binding<Bean?>(
    get: {
        self.chooseBeanID
    },
    set: {
        self.chooseBeanID = $0
        print($0)
        //here you can get your current Bean object with $0 or after setting it to chooseBeanID. 
        //You might call your function with that object or do operations here
    }
)) {
    ForEach(beans, id: \.self) { bean in
        HStack {
            Text(bean.roaster ?? "unknown")
            Text(bean.name ?? "unknown")
            Text(bean.roastStyle ?? "unknown")
        }.tag(bean as Bean?)
    }
 }
```

Then you can keep track of the selected Bean and access all variables. You might do a Proxy Binding for the selection, and then you could run any action with the new selected item.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your reply. I tried to do so. my problem is now, that the Picker isn't selecting the Bean anymore.        
                Picker("Bohne", selection: $chooseBeanID2) {
                            ForEach(beans, id: \.self) { bean in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(bean.roaster ?? "unknown")
                                    Text(bean.name ?? "unknown")                                       }.tag(bean.self) // tried also.. tag(bean.id) ... tag(bean)  
                            }
                        }

Comment: @Andre Just fixed it, now its working :) Actually the Tag is necessary to declare the correct optional type. The self type would be Bean, however as we use Bean? we need to cast it.

Comment: Perfect Thank you. it is now selecting. will try to move on :)